# Laravel 5.0 Custom Validation Method not Found

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

i have a custom validation rules that works on my dev server but when i push it to my production server, it's become error. It said that Method [validationFoo] not Found. here is my code :

AppServiceProvide.php

```
public function boot()
{
Validator::extend('is_even_length', function($attribute, $value, $params, $validator){
    return strlen($value)%2==0;
});

Validator::replacer('is_even_length', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $params) {
    return str_replace('_', ' ' , 'The '. $attribute .' must have an even length !!' );
});
}
```

and here is my controller

```
  $rules = [
        'test' => 'required|max:16|min:12|is_even_length'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::get(),$rules);`
```

i have include

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

on my AppServiceProvider.php and my controller

is there any wrong on my code?

Thanks

Comment: Your error says `Method [validationFoo] not Found`. This doesn't seem to be related to your custom rule. You might have some test code in your application. Check for more details on the error and see where it's being called.

Comment: @Sandeesh hi, sorry i mean my error is [validationIsEvenLenght] not found. Validator.php line 2615

Comment: There is typo between **`is_even_length`** and **`validationIsEvenLenght`** `gth` and `ght`

Comment: @linktoahref : sry looks like i have typo here. this is what my error message : Method [validateIsEvenLength] does not exist. and this is my custom validation rule : is_even_length

Comment: @Sandy looks like you're custom rule isn't getting registered and laravel is defaulting to find the method in it's base class. Try running `php artisan clear-compiled`. Also you can use `use Input;` and `use Validator;` since they have facades registered.

Comment: @Sandeesh : wow it's works !! Thanks :D

Comment: @Sandy glad it could help. I'll add that as an answer to help anyone who stumble on this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your custom rule isn't getting registered and laravel is defaulting to find the method in it's base class. Try running `php artisan clear-compiled`. Also you can use `use Input;` and `use Validator;` since they have facades registered.

Answer (score 1):

this is because `is_even_length` does not exists in `resources/lang/en/validation.php`

in your boot

```
Validator::extend('is_even_length', function($attribute, $value, $parameters,  
validator) {
     if(!empty($value) && (strlen($value) % 2) == 0){
         return true;
     }
     return false;
});
```

then in `resources/lang/en/validation.php` add your validation message like

```
'is_even_length' => "The :attribute must have an even length.",
```

Comment: it is still error, i am not add that on my resources/lang/en/validation.php and it is work well on my dev server and my localhost